# How to properly configure fail2ban to ban IP if it is accessing some wrong files

Tags: fail2ban

I am trying to configure [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) on my test server. I want just to temporary block any script bots that try to probe my site. So everything that has `cgi-bin`, `admin`, `setup.php` and so on. I previously reviewed all that generates 404 errors with something like `grep "HTTP/1.1\" 404" access.log | awk '{print $7 } ' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n` in my access.log.

I ensured that none of my urls have none of these parts.

So after installation I created `jail.local` and has not done anything with `jail.conf`. My file looks like this (I want to block IP for 10 minutes):

```
[DEFAULT]
ignoreip  = 127.0.0.1
bantime   = 600
destemail = myemail
banaction = iptables-multiport
action    = %(action_mwl)s


[apache-script-bots]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-script-bots
logpath  = /var/log/apache2/access.log
maxretry = 1
```

I also created `apache-script-bots.conf` in `filter.d` folder, which has only this inside:

```
[Definition]
failregex = (admin|setup.php|main.php|w00tw00t|web-console|.jsp|manager|cgi-bin)
ignoreregex =
```

When restarting fail2ban it shows me that everything is ok. But when I try to test whether my jail works by trying to triggering it with: `mydomain/main.php` I see that I am not jailed.

When I check the status of fail2ban it tells me that my jail is working

```
fail2ban-client status
Status
|- Number of jail:  2
`- Jail list:       ssh, apache-script-bots
```

I assume that the problem is with regular expression, but can not understand why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell fail2ban (via the regex) where in the log entry it will find a `<HOST>` so that it can then ban that host. For a normal access log that would be at the beginning of the line so

```
<HOST> -.*(w00tw00t|main.php|setup.php)
```

would work but may not do exactly what you want as it would match the relevant triggers anywhere in the log entry.

---

You may want to try something like

```
<HOST> -.*(/w00tw00t|/main.php |setup.php )
```

which should tie some of the strings down to more specific locations